# Vendor identifiers Does not work in iOS Version 5.0

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uniqueidentifier

I'm using the Vendor Identifier since use of UDID is deprecated, but after using this App does not work in the devices with iOS version less than 6.0. Can anyone tell me what needs to be done ? Will the app only be supported in iOS 6.0 and above ? How do I make my app function in devices with iOS version less than 6.0 ? Below is the code i'm using :

```
static NSString *uniqueIdentifier = nil;
id vendorIdObject = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
uniqueIdentifier = [vendorIdObject UUIDString];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this (note, the identifier this returns is not bound to the device and will change if the user deletes and re-installs the app):

```
NSString* uniqueIdentifier = nil;
if( [UIDevice instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)] ) {
  // iOS 6+
  uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
} else {
  // before iOS 6, so just generate an identifier and store it
  uniqueIdentifier = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"identiferForVendor"];
  if( !uniqueIdentifier ) {
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    uniqueIdentifier = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
    CFRelease(uuid);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:uniqueIdentifier forKey:@"identifierForVendor"];
  }
}
```

This will generate an identifier pre-iOS-6 and store it in defaults so that it's generally the same identifier. If you have a keychain group and a suite of apps that need to use the identifier in a similar fashion to `identifierForVendor`, you could stash it in the keychain instead of user defaults.

Comment: User defaults can be restored from backup to another device. It may be better to store your identifier in a file excluded from backup ([QA1719](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/)).

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

1. Check the iOS version at runtime
2. If it is iOS 6+ use `identifierForVendor`
3. If it is less than iOS 6 use `uniqueIdentifier`

**Edit:** As rmaddy said, the appstore will reject the app.

So the best way is to use **`CFUUIDCreate()`**:

```
CFUUIDRef locUDIDRef = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);  
CFStringRef locUDIDRefString = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, locUDIDRef);  
NSString *locUDID = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *) locUDIDRefString];  
CFRelease(locUDIDRef);  
CFRelease(uuidStringRef);
```

Reference [Alternatives for UDID in iOS 6](http://midhunmp-iostips.blogspot.in/2013/05/unique-identifier-in-ios-6.html)

Comment: Except for the tiny little detail that Apple will reject any app that calls `uniqueIdentifier`.

Comment: @Midhun, I have already done those steps and still Apple checks if it contains "uniqueIdentifier". So how is it possible to get it work iOS version less than 6.0

Comment: @rmaddy: you are right. so best way is to use `CFUUIDCreate()`

Comment: @MidhunMP creating a ID using CFUUIDCreate is unique if a user uninstalls and re-installs the app: you will get a new one each time. So this is would not be a good technique to be used.

Comment: @NISHANgp Even in iOS 6.1+, the user can reset the vendor id at anytime. It's not longer possible to uniquely identify the device forever, you can just uniquely identify it for a given session that may be reset. So, it's pretty much the same thing. When the new version of the OS comes out, even old apps not linked against it are going to get a lie returned by `uniqueIdentifier`, so it's important to redesign for this new paradigm now.

Comment: @JasonCoco storing the values in NSUserDefaults is this really a recommended one by Apple. Since due to the security concerns any hacker will be able to hack the stuffs from the app if anything is stored in NSUserDefaults. Is this a good method ?

Comment: @NISHANgp It's just a UUID that persists... although I'm not sure what you're using this for. There's nothing secure about `-identifierForVendor` or the original `-uniqueIdentifier` methods, so there shouldn't be any security concern. You shouldn't store use passwords or confidential information there, but mostly because the user defaults session is the wrong place. You could keep this identifier in a file or the keychain or wherever. For use in the example, the user defaults is just convenient.

Comment: @JasonCoco Is it recommended to use OpenUDID ? Any possible issues using this ??

Comment: @NISHANgp I don't think it's necessary or provides anything of use that the code above or the code I posted doesn't, but it depends on your needs. Only you know what you're using the device identifier for and how your app works, so you'll have to evaluate it for your needs. It certainly doesn't add any notion of "security". UUIDs are expected to be unique across time and space but offer no inherent security of any kind.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32385/discussion-between-nishan-gp-and-jason-coco)

Comment: @NISHANgp: even the `identifierForVendor` not persist if all the app from a specific vendor is uninstalled